Почему когда останавливаешь докер не срабатывает событие gunicorn on_exit?
У меня есть docker-compose файл, который запускает nginx и джанго на gunicorn. В самом файле конфигураций gunicorn есть логика, которая должна выполняться, когда сервер останавливаеться, но она не срабатывает при остановке докер. А если использывать без докера, то она работает.
docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.8'


services:
  gunicorn:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app/static:/app/static
      - ./app/db/db.sqlite3:/app/db/db.sqlite3
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./app/static:/app/static
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - gunicorn

gunicorn.conf.py
import multiprocessing
import sqlite3

from datetime import datetime, timedelta


import pytz



bind = "0.0.0.0:8000"
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1

def on_exit(server):
    connection = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT exit_time FROM game')

    time = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    
    if time is None:
        current_time = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) - timedelta(hours=3)
        cursor.execute('UPDATE game SET exit_time = ?', (current_time,))

        connection.commit()
        connection.close()

Может кто-то знает, как правильно нужно это делать?

Не рекомендую полагаться на логику при остановке, при любой нештатной остановке она всё равно не сработает

А как по другому отлавливать выход из сервера?

Нештатную остановку вы никак не отловите

Понял, спасибо. Просто мне нужно было отловить момент выхода, если пользователь не закрыл старницу(на сервер отсылаеться запрос при выходе из страницы), а сервер вырубился

Да и при нештатном закрытии страницы запрос тоже не отправится, есть подозрение, что вы какую-то шибко ненадёжную архитектуру у себя выстраиваете

ну со страницай у меня более менее все нормально, но вот именно с gunicorn не сошлось))) Вообщем это задание нужно было сделать на pygame, я решил сделать по сложному на django, но что-то пошло не так)))
